# WCF Service invoking - without any reference added

Tags: wcf, service, testing

I want to invoke a wcf service for testing on the http layer. I do not want to add a service reference and create a proxy and invoke. I want to create a new web test(VSTS) which sends a http request to the service and posts(Http post) the request in http body as an xml.

I have service metadata, with which I can see the datacontracts, but the wsdl:operation has only the operation name, wsdl:input is just blank.

On the Contary, an asmx service will have the soap request in the metadata which can be copied as the http request body, with the parameters replaced.

How to build a wcf service xml body from scratch just by looking at the service metadata (no access to the service logs as well), have got just the end point.

It is something like

```
<root>
 <element1>element1</element1>
 <element2>element2</element2>
</root>
```

But, how to find out this, root has to be some thing like

```
<FunctionRequest xmlns=""http://schemas...."" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
```

(tested for a local service and worked)

Now, without having access to service logs(svctraceviewer logs), not able to add a service reference, not able to use svcutil.exe(certificate based service), just only with metadata - wsdl, is there a way to find out the request that is to be sent to service?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to create proxy - either statically by adding a service reference or running svcutil on your service metadata, or you can construct it dynamically totally in code, if you wish.

In that case, you'd have to have your service contract (ISomethingService) at hand, and check out the [ChannelFactory < ISomethingService > ()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx) concept - that should get you started.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you have to do a little work first.

Build the service client by running svcutil.exe on the wsdl/xsd metadata. This will generate a c# with your service and data contract objects. Compile that to an assembly using csc.exe.

See the soap envelope *body* you can create a request object and manually serialize it with data contract serializer. Or you can host the assembly in [WcfSvcHost.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx) and add wcf logging to the config file. In either case you will only have the correct xml for the body, and even that might be wrong if the real service uses xml serializer instead of data contract serializer.

The next part is the hard part because you need to know the security model for the real service. If it only uses certificates for SSL and server identification, you should be able to send the xml using WebClient. But if it uses mutual certs and/or security tokens, you pretty much have to create a channelfactory by hand with the right bindings.